# total all different numbers on one function that is looping

Tags: python

I wanna add the total of all bill using this function that is looping depends of what amount to add

```
    calls = int(input("Input Call Duration (seconds) : "))

    if (calls <= 60):
        bill = 0

    if (calls > 60 and calls <= 120):
        bill = (calls-60)*0.5

    if (calls > 120):
        bill = (calls-60)*0.5+20

    bill = bill + 20
    print("Call Duration =", calls, "\nCost = ", bill)
```

This was the code im using it to loop

```
while n < int(number_virtuals):

calls = int(input("Input Call Duration (seconds) : "))

if (calls <= 60):  # first 200 call free
    bill = 0

if (calls > 60 and calls <= 120):  # 200 free after 1 re/call
    bill = (calls-60)*0.5

if (calls > 120):  # first 200 free 200-500 1 re/call after 2 re/call.
    bill = (calls-60)*0.5+20

bill = bill + 20  # add 100 Rs rental
print("Call Duration =", calls, "\nCost = ", bill)

n += 1

dataList.append({"number_virtuals": number_virtuals, "Bills": bill + bill})
print(dataList)
```

Output

*

> ```
> How many virtuals are you requesting? 2
> enter number of calls60
> Call Duration = 60 
> Cost =  20
> enter number of calls120
> Call Duration = 120 
> Cost =  50.0
> [{'number_virtuals': '2', 'Bills': 150.0}]
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

- 

I want to total all the collected bills to the print(dataList) from various users but it gets what is the last bill value and adds it up to the last also, but i can't

Comment: Your indentation is not correct. Is this how your code looks? You need to move all the lines after while by 4 spaces inside.

Comment: What is this even doing? There is e.g. `calls = int(input("Input Call Duration (seconds) : "))`. This asks for "number of seconds" but assigns to a variable later used as "number of calls".

Comment: Before posting code please be sure that it runs correctly. i.e. We should be able to copy and paste it and have it reproduce the events related to your question. You can read this meta for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I indented the code and ran it. It works fine. I also added a few comments to help you.

Two key things.

1. You should initialize bill = 0 inside the loop.
2. You are adding bill twice before you store it into the list. See the .append() line. Removed one bill. If you want to double the bill, then you can keep it as bill + bill.

Here's the updated code:

```
number_virtuals = 3 #set the loop to go 3 times
n = 0 #set counter to zero
dataList = [] #initialized the list
while n < int(number_virtuals):
    calls = int(input("Input Call Duration (seconds) : "))
    
    bill = 0 #added this line. Initialize bill each time

    if (calls <= 60):  # first 200 call free
        bill = 0

    if (calls > 60 and calls <= 120):  # 200 free after 1 re/call
        bill = (calls-60)*0.5

    if (calls > 120):  # first 200 free 200-500 1 re/call after 2 re/call.
        bill = (calls-60)*0.5+20

    bill = bill + 20  # add 100 Rs rental
    print("Call Duration =", calls, "\nCost = ", bill)

    n += 1

    dataList.append({"number_virtuals": number_virtuals, "Bills": bill})
    #you are storing bill + bill. It should be just bill
print(dataList)
```

The output of the above code is:

Note I gave 3 iterations. So the list has 3 elements.

```
Input Call Duration (seconds) : 40
Call Duration = 40 
Cost =  20
Input Call Duration (seconds) : 70
Call Duration = 70 
Cost =  25.0
Input Call Duration (seconds) : 150
Call Duration = 150 
Cost =  85.0
[{'number_virtuals': 3, 'Bills': 20}, {'number_virtuals': 3, 'Bills': 25.0}, {'number_virtuals': 3, 'Bills': 85.0}]
```

For 40 minutes, it gives the correct bill as 20.

For 70 minutes, it gives the correct bill of (70-60) = 10 * 0.5 + 20 = 25

For 140 minutes, it gives the correct bill of (150 - 60) = 90 * 0.5 + 40 = 85

The comments in your code says first 200 calls free. However you are looking for calls <= 60. Do you want to make it 200? Is it 200 seconds? 200 calls? Don't know. If you have more details, please post them in the question section so this answer can be modified to meet the correct requirements.

Comment: about the 200 calls free, i forgot to remove them, its still about the seconds. and your answer was so helpful!

Comment: Excellent. If the response answered your question, you can mark the question as answered and upvote the response.